# How to change the entry's font size in gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtkmm4

I am trying to make an application, and i put an entry in it, when i write something in the entry, its font is small and not compatible with the entry's size,
Is there any way to change its size

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have an entry, but when i write something in it, the font size of it is too small, my question is how to increase the Gtkmm entry's font size

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the time for a long answer but look on the side of css providers in gtkmm. You have some examples in the documentation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).